# Creating elements of observableArrays as observables (deep mapping)

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm new to the mapping plugin and think that I'm missing something obvious.

How can I get ko.mapping to 'deeply' create members of observable arrays as observables themselves? I've looked at 'create callbacks' and 'options' in the documentation, but don't see anything obvious.

I have quite a large object model and so would prefer not to have to bind the viewModel by hand. Also, as a side issue perhaps, there is a need to add elements dynamically as observables as well.

**html**

```
<p>
    here, ko.mapping succesfully creates an observable...<br/>
    <input data-bind="value:someText, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"></input>
</p>

<p>
    however, here, the contents of the observable array are not observables...</br>    
    <span data-bind="foreach: { data: years, as: 'year' }">

   <input data-bind="value:year, valueUpdate:'afterkeydown'"></input>

    <br />
    </span>
    <button data-bind="click:function(){addYear();}">add</button>
</p>

<p><br /><br /><div data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root)"></div></p>
```

​

**javascript**

```
var model={    
    someText: 'Hello',        
    years:[2000,2001,2002]
};

var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
viewModel.addYear=function(){viewModel.years.push(ko.observable(""));}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

​

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/damiensawyer/Sfg4K/) a jsFiddle link

Thanks very much for your help,

DS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to change your array to be an array of properties instead of just numbers.  If you have just an array numbers, the mapping plugin doesn't covert them to observables.

```
var model={    
    someText: 'Hello',        
    years:[{item:2000},{item:2001},{item:2002}]
    };
```

See the [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/photo_tom/Sfg4K/16/)